# Original song used to make VOICES tilt-six Remix feat. Miku Hatsune?

Tags: vocaloid, hatsune-miku

What was the original song that was remixed to make VOICES tilt-six Remix feat. Miku Hatsune?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbryVBMkCeU

Answer (score 1):

according to the [Vocaloid Wikia](http://vocaloid.wikia.com/wiki/VOICES) it's based on an EDM, non-lyrical song of the same name.

> **"VOICES"** is a remixed Japanese song by tilt-six featuring Hatsune Miku. The song is based off of an EDM, non-lyrical song of the same name. The video was created as a collaboration between iXima, tilt-six and Sony to promote the new [Sony XPERIA smartphone](http://www.sonymobile.com/us/xperia/)

the page list [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_Lq91eDlOI) as the original with the description saying

> The official, original version of the song "VOICES", created to promote the Sony XPERIA smartphone.